# How to make div appearence animated when that section reach in browsers view without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am working on a site.i want when the page scrolls and reach on the 'partner' section.the divs in the grid appear differently.
    I hope my question is not confusing! :|
    i want something like dis:
    https://www.mycartracks.com/?t1&utm_expid=48608364-9.0rQQlaAFTVuLCNWFL2kmBw.2
    (From the most common business use)
    Thank you in advance .
    Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/juhimathur/3vysbt1s/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=3vysbt1s

```
here is my code:
<section id="partner" class="use m-t-lg" style="margin-top:5px">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="Partner_portion">


                    <!-- Service Category Row-->

                        <!--First category-->

                    <div layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-sm="column" layout-fill="true" class="service_apps layout-fill layout-xs-column layout-sm-column layout-row">

                        <!--Service Box 1-->
                        <!--Service Box 2-->
                        <div class="single_app col-md-4 flex-33 partner_content">
                            <div class="use_block">
                                <div class="use_blockcontent">
                                    <div class="use-block-text" id="#test">

                                        <h2>Rental Package</h2><br />
                                        <p class="textsmall">
                                            Cost effective way of starting ‘Vehicle Tracking’business with minimum upfront cost and time.
                                        </p>
                                        <br />
                                        <p style="color:#43C6DB;cursor:pointer">Read More</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--Service Box 3-->
                        <div class="single_app col-md-4 flex-33 partner_imgsection" style="background-image:url('images/box.png')">
                            <div class="use_block">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--Service Box 3-->

                        <div class="single_app col-md-4 flex-33 partner_content" style="-moz-animation:ease-in-out;-moz-animation-delay:2s">
                            <div class="use_block">

                                <div class="use_blockcontent">
                                    <div class="use-block-text">

                                        <h2> Custom Package</h2><br />
                                        <p class="textsmall">
                                            Customized solution specific to a segment related transportation industry
                                        </p>
                                        <br />
                                        <p style="color:#43C6DB;cursor:pointer">Read More</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>






                    <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" class="app_row layout-align-center-center layout-column">
                        <!--First category-->

                        <div layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-sm="column" layout-fill="true" class="service_apps layout-fill layout-xs-column layout-sm-column layout-row">

                            <!--Service Box 1-->
                            <!--Service Box 2-->
                            <div class="single_app col-md-4 flex-33 partner_imgsection" style="background-image:url('images/pie-chart.png')">
                                <div class="use_block">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--Service Box 3-->
                            <div class="single_app col-md-4 flex-33 partner_content">
                                <div class="use_block">
                                    <div class="use_blockcontent">
                                        <div class="use-block-text">

                                            <p class="textmiddle">
                                                Take Your Business A Step Further<br />Host Your Own Tracking System
                                                <br>
                                            <p style="color:#43C6DB;cursor:pointer">Read More</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--Service Box 3-->


                            <div class="single_app col-md-4 flex-33 partner_imgsection" style="background-image:url('images/coins.png')">
                                <div class="use_block">







                                </div>
                            </div>



                        </div>


                    </div>





                    <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" class="app_row layout-align-center-center layout-column">
                        <!--First category-->

                        <div layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-sm="column" layout-fill="true" class="service_apps layout-fill layout-xs-column layout-sm-column layout-row">

                            <!--Service Box 1-->
                            <!--Service Box 2-->
                            <div class="single_app col-md-4 flex-33 partner_content">
                                <div class="use_block">
                                    <div class="use_blockcontent">
                                        <div class="use-block-text">

                                            <h2> Marketing and Sales material</h2><br />
                                            <p class="textsmall">
                                                All the material that you need to make a sale is our responsibility.
                                            </p>
                                            <br />
                                            <p style="color:#43C6DB;cursor:pointer">Read More</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--Service Box 3-->
                            <div class="single_app col-md-4 flex-33 partner_imgsection" style="background-image:url('images/people.png');">
                                <div class="use_block">







                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <!--Service Box 3-->


                            <div class="single_app col-md-4 flex-33 partner_content">
                                <div class="use_block">

                                    <div class="use_blockcontent">
                                        <div class="use-block-text">

                                            <h2>Training and Support</h2><br />
                                            <p class="textsmall">
                                                We guide you with every step taken in a new direction and ensure that you benefit from our experience.
                                            </p>
                                            <br />
                                            <p style="color:#43C6DB;cursor:pointer">Read More</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>



                        </div>


                    </div>



                </div><!--partner portion closed-->
            </div><!--container closed-->
        </section><!--partner section closed-->
```

Comment: Where's the javascript?

Comment: I haven't used js

Comment: Your example website is using wow.js. just take a look at their elements. they have a class called wow and fade-in-left or fade-in-right. you said you want no jquery? do you mean no javascript at all?

Comment: i already tried wow.js but it affects other effects on my site and even not creating any animation.i tried exact same as example site but not working :( Dats y i am searching for javascript function dat creates same effect :|

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using pure CSS. Have a look to css animations
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: i need animation after specific section load

Comment: Create a new css class containing the animation code and assign it to the element that must be animated. It's only another css class!

Comment: I already tried it.but when entire page loads the animation finished and when i scroll down to section that i want to animate seems static :|